# How to read a string under <b> tag

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have string which contains some **heading data** into `<b>` tag and some **body data** under `<br>` tag.
So I want to retrieve Heading and body data into two different string array.

So my question is how to split the string and got desired result.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, could you maybe post an example of the String you'd like to parse with the desired result?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not clear what you're asking here. What does "contains some heading data into `<b>` tag" mean? What does `some body data under `<br>` tag" mean? An example would help a **lot**. Also: Are you really trying to do this in Java? Or did you mean to tag JavaScript instead?

Comment: string is like that and i want to get all the strings which are in bold tag in a string array and strings which are in <br> tag in another array.    so i want to know is there any string method for doing this.                             <b>Data</b><br>A,b,c</br><b>Audits</b><br>Pwc,TCS,INfo</br>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be (maybe) using the String method called `matches()`.

You can find the appropriate usage in the official Oracle Document which is available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)).

Have a nice day!